# How to avoid calling asInstanceOf in Scala with family polymorphism

Tags: scala, casting

By design, we know for sure that we have an instance of `HourlyDateFormat`

How to avoid calling asInstanceOf in this case (i.e how to help the compiler to infer the type) ?

```
  sealed trait StorageLayout extends Product with Serializable
  case object Hourly         extends StorageLayout
  case object Daily          extends StorageLayout

  sealed trait DateFormat[S <: StorageLayout]

  sealed abstract class HourlyDateFormat extends DateFormat[Hourly.type] {
    def format(localDate: LocalDate): String         = ???
    def format(localDateTime: LocalDateTime): String = ???
  }

  sealed abstract class DailyDateFormat extends DateFormat[Daily.type] {
    def format(localDate: LocalDate): String = ???
  }

  class Log[S <: StorageLayout](storageLayout: S, dateFormat: DateFormat[S]) {
    def getPath(date: LocalDate): String =
      dateFormat match {
        case hdf: HourlyDateFormat => hdf.format(date)
        case ddf: DailyDateFormat  => ddf.format(date)
      }
    @SuppressWarnings(Array("org.wartremover.warts.AsInstanceOf"))
    def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit ev: S =:= Hourly.type): String = {
      assert(ev == ev)
      dateFormat.asInstanceOf[HourlyDateFormat].format(date)
    }
  }
```

Comment: It may help if you can describe what are you allowed to change, and what is your ultimate goal? How do you want to use `Log`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be something like this:

```
class Log[S <: StorageLayout, D <: DateFormat[S]](storageLayout: S, dateFormat: D) {
  def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit ev: D <:< HourlyDateFormat): String =
    dateFormat.format(date)
}
```

However, I don't think you've designed this the right way. It'd probably be better to have a separate trait for each type of format. This makes it more scalable, since you don't need to add a case in your match expression for each different class, the right method gets selected automatically at runtime. You still have to use those evidence parameters, which I don't like, but it still feels cleaner to me.

Edit: I've updated the code so that everything extends `FormatLocalDate` and you only need an evidence parameter for `getPath(LocalDateTime)`

```
sealed trait FormatLocalDate[S <: StorageLayout] {
  def format(localDate: LocalDate): String
}
sealed trait FormatLocalDateTime[S <: StorageLayout] extends FormatLocalDate[S] {
  def format(localDate: LocalDateTime): String
}

sealed abstract class HourlyDateFormat extends FormatLocalDateTime[Hourly.type] {
  def format(localDate: LocalDate): String = ???
  def format(localDateTime: LocalDateTime): String = ???
}
sealed abstract class DailyDateFormat extends FormatLocalDate[Daily.type] {
  def format(localDate: LocalDate): String = ???
}

class Log[S <: StorageLayout, D <: FormatLocalDate[S]](storageLayout: S, dateFormat: D) {
  def getPath(date: LocalDate): String =
    dateFormat.format(date)

  def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit ev: D <:< FormatLocalDateTime[S]): String =
    dateFormat.format(date)
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/K3sljIjnTFylI6cpcjt3cw)

Comment: I'm wondering if we can avoid to mention this implicit `(implicit ev: D <:< FormatLocalDate[S])` because all concrete `DateFormat` will be a subclass of this one by design.

Comment: @YannMoisan In that case, you can just make `FormatLocalDate` the super trait instead of `FormatDate`. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 5):

Try to add one more implicit parameter

```
def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit ev: S =:= Hourly.type, ev1: DateFormat[S] =:= HourlyDateFormat): String = {
  //assert(ev == ev)
  dateFormat.format(date)
}
```

<strike>Assertion looks strange: `assert(ev == ev)`.</strike>

Or just

```
def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit ev1: DateFormat[S] =:= HourlyDateFormat): String
```

---

Fixed version (I added one more type parameter, it's now similar to the first **@user**'s version)

```
class Log[S <: StorageLayout, D <: DateFormat[S]](storageLayout: S, dateFormat: D) {
  def getPath(date: LocalDate): String =
    dateFormat match {
      case hdf: HourlyDateFormat => hdf.format(date)
      case ddf: DailyDateFormat  => ddf.format(date)
    }
  def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit
                                   ev: S =:= Hourly.type,
                                   ev1: D <:< HourlyDateFormat,
  ): String = {
    dateFormat.format(date)
  }
}

val log = new Log(Hourly, new HourlyDateFormat(){})
print(log.getPath(LocalDateTime.now()))
```

Comment: The assertion is probably to suppress the unused warning.  Which, in your second example shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Given that there could be multiple subclasses of `DailyDateFormat` (that's why it's abstract), I've changed `=:=` with `<:<` but it doesn't work. `new Log(Hourly, DateFormat.HOURLY_LEADING_ZEROS).getPath(LocalDate.now))`.Cannot prove that DateFormat[Hourly.type] <:< HourlyDateFormat.

Comment: @YannMoisan Yeap, testing code was absent in your question. See update.

Answer (score 5):

Generally things like that are kind-of type-classy, so I would do it this way instead:

```
trait DailyFormatter[S] {
  def formatDate(localDate: LocalDate): String
}
trait HourlyFormatter[S] {
  def formatDateTime(localDateTime: LocalDateTime): String
}

implicit val dailyFormats: DailyFormatter[Daily]
implicit val hourFormats: DailyFormatter[Hourly] with HourlyFormatter[Hourly]

class Log[S <: StorageLayout](storageLayout: S, dateFormat: DateFormat[S]) {

  def getPath(date: LocalDate)(implicit formater: DailyFormatter[S]): String =
    formater.formatDate(date)

  def getPath(date: LocalDateTime)(implicit formater: HourlyFormatter[S]): String =
    formater.formatDateTime(date)
}
```

It has the advantage that you don't have to be aware of existence of types `HourlyDateFormat` and `DailyDateFormat` to make it work.

Comment: The dateFormat well as the storageLayout are unnecessary.

Comment: I agree that `DailyFormater` could be removed but then the design would be inconsistent.

Comment: What do you mean with inconsistent?

Comment: Given that there could be multiple subclasses of `DailyDateFormat` (that's why it's abstract), how to use type classes ?

Comment: @YannMoisan It still works with different implementations of the formatter: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/fLSDbzP5RMipXyYIxD6w8g